# Wordpress Ajax in plugins

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Im porting a plugin for Wordpress from a script, and Im finding it very difficult to update my settings through ajax, or add new options..

I want to use ajax since my original script uses ajax.

What is the best way to approach this?

I have already read through [Ajax In Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and all of its resources..

Here is the main structure of the plugin

myplugin/js/custom.js <- This has all the ajax requests using jQuery-Ajax
myplugin/ajax/ <- in here are all the php files that recieve the settings to be updated.
myplugin/plugin.php <- This loads the javascript file.

The javascript is loaded using :

```
wp_register_script( 'custom_script', plugins_url('/js/custom.js', __FILE__) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_script' );
```

Any help is greately appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it took me some time to realize how the whole thing works, but here is the deal:

You use the following example code:
**Javascript**
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "admin-ajax.php",
    data: {action: "DoMyAjaxStuff"}
    success: function(){ }
    });

**PHP**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_DoMyAjaxStuff', 'myajaxfunc');

function myajaxfunc{
//Do stuff here
}
```